# Archaic Greek sampi and stigma in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How may one have access to \stigma, \Stigma,\varstigma, \sampi and \Sampi from teubner, as in Table 428 of the Comprehensive Latex font catalogue, while in math mode?

Comment: Note that the document you refer to is called the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive), not to be confused with the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/about.html) (I initially did not realize you meant the first and not the second).

Comment: My question is not answered by https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645190/textsymbol-in-mathmode, which concerns a special symbol in the tipa package.

Comment: The question may seem different at first but it is essentially the same: how to use a non-math symbol in math. The solutions that are mentioned in the first answer there also work for your situation (I tested it): `$\textrm{\Stigma}$` and `$\text{\Stigma}$` (the second solution needs `\usepackage{amsmath}`) both show the symbol in math mode.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks! So that raises the question as to whether it is best to explicitly answer the questions which others are concerned with, or leaving it for them to work out details that may not be so clear to them.

Comment: It is indeed sometimes difficult to judge if a related question is similar enough to close a question as a duplicate of the other, and even more so if the similarity is easy to see and apply for the person posting the new question and future visitors that come across the new question. In this case I decided that the questions, and especially the answers, were sufficiently similar. I'm sorry for the initial confusion this caused, but fortunately the comment system proved useful to clarify how the other question applies.

Comment: It is important that such questions are closed without a new answer being provided, otherwise there is a high risk of useful information being spread out across multiple questions. This makes that information more difficult to find. The StackExchange model is intended to collect all the information on a particular issue in one place, and duplicate closure is an important part of that model.